# Is it possible to configure two VMs on a Ubuntu KVM host with two static IPs

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization

I have two static IPs, e.g 220.220.220.220 and 220.220.220.221. I have one network card on the host machine. Can i configure each VM to have it's own IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two network cards to allow two VMs.  The host will act like a network switch, and send the packets where they need to go.

Comment: Would you know how I should configure this Womble? I'm new to the VM stuff and I'm really lost. Thanks.

Comment: No, I don't use the commodity VM management stuff.

Comment: Hello Womble, would I need three IPs for my two VMs — 2 for the guest VMs and one for the KVM host? Am I right?

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments, ask them in questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. With 2 IP addresses you can configure 2 machines to have their own IP addresses (does not matter if they are virtual or real machines). If you set up 2 virtual machines with these IP addresses, you do not have any left for the host machine (which is often fine and some times even desirable).